# rename file .txt after converting pdf to text php

Tags: php, pdf

```
<?php 
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('LAPORAN PAP KASIR.pdf');
$a->decodePDF();

$fp = fopen('C:\xampp\htdocs\stki\search_engine\aplikasi_3\doc\text\myText.txt',"wb");
$content = $a->output();
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

The code executes normally..no problem. but the name of the results file (.txt) is not the same as before in the converted file(.pdf). how to give a name to convert results (. txt) to be the same as before in the convert file name (. pdf) and stored in the directory
please help me

Comment: Where is the name incorrect? What is the name now, and what do you want it to be? You have not provided enough information.

Comment: the name of the file that I want to convert is LAPORAN PAP KASIR.pdf and I convert it to a txt file and I keep it in the directory. but the name is not stored in the same directory with the name before that convert LAPORAN PAP KASIR.pdf.  I want to ask how to become LAPORAN PAP KASIR.pdf be LAPORAN PAP KASIR.txt and stored in the directory C:\xampp\htdocs\stki\search_engine\aplikasi_3\doc\text\

Comment: Have you tried using `file_put_contents`?

Comment: placed where? Can you write the code? thanks

Comment: Why did you append 'b' in your `fopen`? As far as I understand, that is a designation of a _binary file_ and you are trying to save a text file. Have you tried it without the `b`?

Comment: after I tried to remove the 'b' turns out its the same result, pdf conversion results written in a txt file. and then i ask question, how in the name of the text file conversion result is the same as in the pdf file name

Comment: What is the resultant file name? Not the one you want, but what it currently produces?

Comment: the current generated text file and stored in the directory

Comment: No, what file name is produced by your current code? What is the text file that is output named?

Comment: The resulting file name is currently myText.txt, I want the file name is LAPORAN PAP KASIR.txt and I do not understand the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
include('class.pdf2text.php');
// make sure paths have trailing slash or are empty
$pdfPath = '';
$txtPath = '/home/.../';
$filename = 'LAPORAN PAP KASIR';
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename($pdfPath . $filename.'.pdf');
$a->decodePDF();

file_put_contents($txtPath . $filename.'.txt', $a->output());
?>
```

Comment: there results are still stored in a directory with pdf files, if I want to save the results in a directory how?